# How to limit flow between streams in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, node-streams

I have a `readStream` piped to `writeStream`. Read stream reads from an internet and write stream writes to my local database instance. I noticed that read speed is much faster than write speed and my app memory usage rises until it reaches

```
JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I suspect that it accumulates read data in the NodeJS app like this:
[image]

How can I limit read stream so it reads only what write stream is capable of writing at the given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so long story short - mechanism you need to be aware of to solve these kind of issues is `backpressure`. It is not a problem when you are using standard `node`'s `pipe()`. I am using custom fan-out to multiple streams thus it happened

You can read about it here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

This solution is not ideal as it will block read-stream whenever any of fan-out write streams is blocked but it gives general idea on how to approach this problem

```js
combinedStream.pipe(transformer).on('data', async (data: DbObject) => {
  const writeStream = dbClient.getStreamForTable(data.table);
  if (!writeStream.write(data.csv)) {
    combinedStream.pause();
    await new Promise((resolve) => writeStream.once('drain', resolve));
    combinedStream.resume();
  }
});
```